# Error while playing Audio file for Alexa "AudioPlayer is currently an unsupported namespace"

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing a Alexa skill ,it basically plays a set of audio files stored on S3 based on different invocations.

I have included all the intents required for the audio.Testing on theAlexa skills web simulator. When it has to play the media,It gives the error."AudioPlayer is currently an unsupported namespace".

Following is the line to invoke audio player.

```
this.response.audioPlayerPlay(playBehavior, podcast.url, token, null,offsetInMilliseconds);
```

Following the documentation

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/audioplayer.html#play

Not sure what is the problem , as i see only  one popup coming at the bottom of the screen with the error. PFA for the screenshot.

Nothing much i could figure out from the device logs .

```
{
"header": {
    "namespace": "AudioPlayer",
    "name": "Play",
    "messageId": "5e045877-5961-47c5-8536-f744e52e45b7",
    "dialogRequestId": "68d45ba0-0a07-4b3a-9ed6-2a4f9aec1090"
},
"payload": {
    "audioItem": {
        "audioItemId": "amzn1.as-ct.v1.ThirdPartySdkSpeechlet#ACRI#url#ACRI#{\"directedCustomerId\":\"amzn1.ask.account.AGTPFQMY4J7GPQXFR7GWAFUGXPGVAJO5DCXU4I3NM5PVNIZ53LFRBLQLD4EGSPX3W5RY6I5XYQFTFJRWLJBHDBBIJNAKU2JEGNTDPK6PCDUMRBXUNOZ26CNVMVIH75GW2B3NVUH6SKOAM3BDFVSJ33DGUUWZHNW5XYZ7YTG73FIE2BF2MVRYXPXHRBMG2ZO5YE4IMBFBWL3IBXA\",\"modelKey\":\"amzn1.ask.skill.22c39f48-18bc-4c65-a126-6bc1f7ff4d66\",\"obfuscatedCustomerId\":\"A336WR8U44ZY26\",\"token\":\"0\"}",
        "stream": {
            "offsetInMilliseconds": 0,
            "expiryTime": "2019-04-10T23:50:30+0000",
            "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/sumanth-alexa-skill-bucket/How+to+Live+Happily+-+Sadhguru+Answers.mp3",
            "token": "amzn1.as-ct.v1.ThirdPartySdkSpeechlet#ACRI#url#ACRI#{\"directedCustomerId\":\"amzn1.ask.account.AGTPFQMY4J7GPQXFR7GWAFUGXPGVAJO5DCXU4I3NM5PVNIZ53LFRBLQLD4EGSPX3W5RY6I5XYQFTFJRWLJBHDBBIJNAKU2JEGNTDPK6PCDUMRBXUNOZ26CNVMVIH75GW2B3NVUH6SKOAM3BDFVSJ33DGUUWZHNW5XYZ7YTG73FIE2BF2MVRYXPXHRBMG2ZO5YE4IMBFBWL3IBXA\",\"modelKey\":\"amzn1.ask.skill.22c39f48-18bc-4c65-a126-6bc1f7ff4d66\",\"obfuscatedCustomerId\":\"A336WR8U44ZY26\",\"token\":\"0\"}"
        }
    },
    "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL"
}
```

}

Has anyone worked on the audio in Amazon skills development , faced similar problems.Anyone who can give me a direction where to look for.

[image: Sscrrenshot]

Comment: Hi , Looks like in the browser emulator audio playing doesn't work.We should test the functionality on the device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes , I got this working on the device . If the skill plays audio , you have to test it on the echo device. If your developer account is same as the account on which Alexa is running. You don't have to do anything apart from adding Amazon registered email id's to Beta Testing.If the accounts are different , you have to deregister and register your echo with the developer account . Follow instructions here https://developer.amazon.com/docs/devconsole/test-your-skill.html#h2_register

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error, audioplayer functionality is not supported in the test function through the browser(or simulator). Just run the skill on an actual device and see if it works.